# Angular datepicker showing wrong text for December month

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular material date picker showing DES for the month December, Expected Month text is DEC
[image: Screenshot]

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [min]="startDate">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: can you post the app.module.ts how you configured the date picker locale?

Comment: I didn't do anything, it will take by default one

Comment: which version of angular and angular-material you are using ?

Comment: 7.3.7  version we are using

Comment: I added an answer please try to update the locale code and let me know if it works for you

Comment: working.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the language of your Datepicker by updating the locale code as mentionned in the code below:

**Component TS**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS,MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-formats-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-formats-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-formats-example.css'],
  providers: [
     { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-US' }, //english
     //{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR' }, //french
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerFormatsExample {
}
```

**HTML File**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="choose date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

You can find more details in the [official documentation](https://v7.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#setting-the-locale-code) of the component.

Hope it helps!